# Can we burninate the [restrict*] tags?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Can we burn all forms of the [restrict](/questions/tagged/restrict) tag? Its too vague of a term.

- [restrict](/questions/tagged/restrict)
- [restriction](/questions/tagged/restriction)
- [restrictions](/questions/tagged/restrictions)
- [restricted](/questions/tagged/restricted)

Comment: I think we should merge them instead of burninating them.

Comment: @AnishGupta - its too vague.

Comment: `restrict` could make sense for C questions, though. `restrict` is quite specific there.

Comment: @Daniel At least [tag:restriction] and [tag:restrictions] should be merged.

Comment: @Anish Yes. Clarified that specifically `restrict` may be a legitimate tag. Not sure, though, it's probably too narrow for a tag.

Comment: all - why don't we mark the [tag:C] ones as [tag:qualifier-restrict]

Comment: Hmm, I'd prefer [tag:restrict-qualifier], reads better.

Comment: I went ahead and retagged the C and C++ (and Cuda) questions about the restrict keyword with [tag:restrict-qualifier]. Browsing through the remaining [tag:restrict] questions, I don't see any remaining language-specific feature-related uses.

Comment: then let it burn!