# Tag Cleanup, Burnination, and Blacklisting: children and learning resources edition

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, clean-up

The following tags need special attention from the community!

### Burnination and Blacklisting

These tags have been audited and are considered prime candidates for burnination and blacklisting.

<strike>books</strike>, <strike>ebook</strike>, <strike>education</strike>, <strike>free-software</strike>, <s>learning-resources</s>, <s>screencast</s>, <s>screencasts</s>, <s>training</s>, **<s>tutorials</s>**, <s>video-tutorials</s>

<s>Please note that [training](/questions/tagged/training) has [course](/questions/tagged/course) and [self-training](/questions/tagged/self-training) as synonyms.</s>

### Significant Cleanup / Vetting for Burnination

These tags were uncovered in the audit and need significant cleaned up before they can be burnination candidates. These tags are either being applied inconsistently, are unnecessary, meta-tags, or otherwise problematic. We need your help to check these tags and make the site better.

[badge](/questions/tagged/badge), [blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs), <s>career-development</s>, [children](/questions/tagged/children), [class](/questions/tagged/class), [cost](/questions/tagged/cost), <s>demonstration</s>, [download](/questions/tagged/download), [ereader](/questions/tagged/ereader), [free](/questions/tagged/free), [interactive](/questions/tagged/interactive), [multilingual](/questions/tagged/multilingual), [or-mapper](/questions/tagged/or-mapper), [page-curl](/questions/tagged/page-curl), [presentation](/questions/tagged/presentation), [publishing](/questions/tagged/publishing), [reference](/questions/tagged/reference), [screenshot](/questions/tagged/screenshot), [self-modifying](/questions/tagged/self-modifying), [shake](/questions/tagged/shake), [software-engineering](/questions/tagged/software-engineering), <s>tag:teaching</s>, <s>terms</s>, <s>tips-and-tricks</s>, [transition](/questions/tagged/transition), [writing](/questions/tagged/writing) [google](/questions/tagged/google) [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) [wikipedia](/questions/tagged/wikipedia) [research](/questions/tagged/research) <s>organizing</s>

Other meta tags needing burnination:

[populate](/questions/tagged/populate)

(please note:  struck tags are ... struck)

Comment: Just so we're clear, "Aarthi wants to burninate [tag:children]".

Comment: I know there's not many left, but can we add [technology-choice], [programmer-skills] and [time-estimation] to the burnination list?

Comment: Sorry.. That title was killing me!

Comment: BTW, I don't have 500 rep on [so], but I'd like to help. It wouldn't really help to suggest edits removing these tags would it? (Of course, I'd fix anything else that needed it in the process).

Comment: @Seth Blacklisting ***List?*** :D

Comment: @Aarthi Well it *is* a list :P

Comment: Heh, for a second I thought [discussion], [burninate-request] and [clean-up] were the last tags in your second list. Long day...

Comment: can we add [project/s] to that list? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173482/remove-project-tag

Comment: Let's address that separately, @About

Comment: @TimStone Burninating books also often seen as a bad sign.

Comment: I made a question regarding [coding-style] as a tag that may need to be burned as well... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192921/what-exactly-is-the-use-of-the-coding-style-tag-if-there-is-code-review

Comment: @Shog9: Hey, check my most recent edit to the above question.  You can blacklist it now.  Oh, also, [training] as well.

Comment: [tag:books] is back with 33 questions. I thought it has been blacklisted (or is it not, because this was before the MSO/MSE split?). The tag wiki says “Career Bookshelf”, but this is only on-topic on MSO, not here. And if you take a look at the questions tagged with it, they are about _any_ book-related topic. Please remove the tag from MSE for good!

Answer (score 8):

About [children](/questions/tagged/children):

There seem to be three uses for this

1. Talking about tiny humans
2. Talking about child nodes in HTML/CSS/JS (most
3. Talking about child processes.

What should probably be done:

- Retag all questions about [child-processes](/questions/tagged/child-processes) as such.
- Remove the tag from questions about human children
- Rename/synonym the tag to [child-nodes](/questions/tagged/child-nodes)

Answer (score 2):

[online-resources](/questions/tagged/online-resources) has been burned.  Please blacklist, as almost all questions were off topic, not constructive, and made me cry.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit: Perhaps this idea isn't the best, but something should be done about the excess of unfulfilled burninations (see the bottom of this post)**

Can this list be maintained as FAQ? I know it's not frequently-asked, but it's probably frequently-wondered. We should keep an updated list of tags which need burnination, tags we've burninated, etc. This should be community wiki.

When people post burninate requests, they can be added to this list (with enough upvotes). This would actually promote action, as it would stay in front of peoples' faces much easier.

*A lot of burninate-requests are lost in the pile of posts, and it would be good for us to maintain a solid list for reference. I don't even need to begin [pointing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142036/can-we-burninate-the-restrict-tags?rq=1) [out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144238/burninate-tags-and-tagging-tags?rq=1) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173482/remove-project-tag?rq=1) [number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147084/pointless-but-popular-tag-pass-can-it-be-burninated) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175332/burn-the-movement) [lost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175135/cleanup-use-tag) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147476/the-use-of-big-tag?rq=1).*

Comment: No, I think this is a bad idea. The community team (i.e. my colleagues and I) along with the developers, keep a close eye on MSO for burnination requests. As requests get fulfilled, it's tidier for us to mark as `[status-completed]` and move onto the next burn/blacklist request.

Comment: @Aarthi A lot more would get done if there were a single coordinated and organized list. Sure, it's easier to do it that way, but that doesn't make it better. Consolidation of information means faster and more thorough action.

Comment: While you're right, this isn't the first time we've done this. Frankly: this system doesn't scale well. Keeping these posts small and focused is a much better way for both us (Stack Exchange) and for you (the community) to handle this. For examples of how this doesn't scale, see [this post on Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5718/91126) (incremental progress for months) and [this post on Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3044) (*very* little progress since an initial clearance). I promise: smaller, focused, *frequent* posts has a better yield over time.

Comment: @Aarthi Hmm. Then maybe there's a better way to handle this in general. I hope you agree that there are WAY too many unhandled burninate requests?

Comment: Are there? Usually Shog9 gets to them fairly expediently and marks them done/declined as needed.

Comment: @Aarthi It took me about five minutes in total to find those seven incomplete burninations. Five of those seven were from memory. Anecdotal, but relevant. Incomplete requests are everywhere.

Comment: Do note, though, that's not to undermine Shog9's work. He's done more than I can count, but we shouldn't, and shouldn't have to, depend on them to fix this.

Comment: First off, yeah - this shouldn't all be me; obviously, I'm not keeping up, which is why Aarthi's vetting *this* set of tags (it takes almost no time to get rid of them, but generally you want to do a bit of sanity-checking first). @Telthien

Comment: @Shog9 Of course - and I don't disagree that this is useful. However, there has to be a better way to do this, and I generally think this will require better coordination.

Comment: @Shog9 Your powers make me jealous. Here I am, burning away old [tag:big] questions, and suddenly everything disappears. You have ruined my evening =[

Comment: Plenty of other tags, @Telthien ;-)