# Should the [training] tag be put out of its misery?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [training](/questions/tagged/training) tag (with synonyms [course](/questions/tagged/course) and [self-training](/questions/tagged/self-training)) seems to have been  [marked for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175909/164376) a while back.

Its current description is:

> DO NOT EVEN THINK OF ASKING THIS QUESTION. List questions (shopping
>   lists) are not suitable for Stack Overflow and are going to be closed
>   as "Not Constructive" immediately.

But if you look at the tag, we're still getting questions with it, several in just the past few days. Shouldn't we just kill it already and blacklist it?

I suppose I should add that some people seem to be using it in the sense of a training/test set in machine learning or model fitting.

Comment: I dunno, it's a nice happy little honeypot for bad questions...

Comment: Its almost done.